# ListView Items doesn't change after removing and inserting new column

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a **ListBox** filled with a few items, in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event i tend to remove any existent extra Columns (ID 1 and bigger), after that, i create a new Column and add Items all over again, but the previous Items stay intact, it's like the `Add()` overload is not working, here is my code:

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            if (listView2.Columns.Count > 1)
            {
                int bla = listView2.Columns.Count;
                for (int i = 1; i < bla; i++)
                {
                    //MessageBox.Show("Removing Column: " + (bla - i));
                    listView2.Columns.RemoveAt(bla - i);
                }
            }

            if (clmnnum[listBox1.SelectedIndex] == 1)
            {
                listView2.SuspendLayout();
                listView2.Columns.Add("Primary Values", 90, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
                listView2.ResumeLayout();
                listView2.Items[0].SubItems.Add(exp[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString());
                listView2.Items[1].SubItems.Add(hpe[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString());
                listView2.Items[2].SubItems.Add(lve[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString());
                listView2.Items[3].SubItems.Add(stre[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString());
                listView2.Items[4].SubItems.Add(powe[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString());
                listView2.Items[5].SubItems.Add(ende[listBox1.SelectedIndex].ToString());
            }
        }
```

The ListBox contains as many items as there are in each Array(clmnnum,exp,hpe,etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is here, you say the Add overload doesn't appear to be working yet you state the problem is the old items are remaining, at least I assume that's what you mean by "the previous items stay intact."

If I understand what you are attempting to do, I would encourage you to clear listView2's items, and have a function to build listView2 as you would like it from nothing each time.

It should at least give you an idea as to what is happening.

Comment: i'll try doing so, but let me explain it more here, i click on an item in the ListBox, i get it's Index, use it to load the values from the mentioned arrays, add a column, then add the SubItems (since the items in the 1st column are already there), after clicking on another item, it deletes the extra column, recreate a new column, but the values stay the same as the previous one, it does not load the new values from the new clicked index.

Comment: So it's like the Subitems.Add is taking values from a cache?

Comment: Exactly, but i thought deleting the Column will delete the items aswell, no ?

Comment: Should do, I'd be tempted to try Column.Items.Clear() before deleting the column just to be sure.

Comment: i actually edited your answer with the solution it has to do actually with the Items.Clear(), idk what are they doing to review it.